# change the text of two labels based on the selected row of a gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, event-handling

I want to change the text of two labels based on the selected row of a gridview.

I keep getting an error that says the public member row does not exist on linkbutton

```
Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim LinkButton1 As LinkButton = DirectCast(sender, LinkButton)

    Dim tour As Label = CType(sender.Row.FindControl("label2"), Label)
    Dim depart As Label = CType(sender.Row.FindControl("label3"), Label)

    test.Text = tour.Text
    test1.Text = depart.Text

    UpdatePanel9.Update()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, `sender` is a `LinkButton`. The property `Row` won't exist on a link button when you reference `sender.Row`. That's why you get the error.

You want to hook into the [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event, which will give you access to the Row more easily.

```
Sub MyGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim myGrid As GridView = TryCast(sender, GridView)
    Dim selectedRow As GridViewRow = myGrid.SelectedRow

    'do something with selected row as needed from here.....

End Sub
```